# hitTestPoint or hitTestObject?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, hittest

I'm needing to make my character land on a ledge and stay there, but it only keeps going straight through it. Would I create an array for all my different ledges and test whenever my character hits them? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Collision detection for floors and stuff is actually alot diffrent from hitTesting in the idea that needs to consistently see that the objects are touching. Try something like this!

```
//loop through all the platform objects to generate the level
var level:Array = new Array();

for (var i=0; i<numChildren; i++)
{
if (getChildAt(i) is platform)
{
    level.push(getChildAt(i).getRect(this));
}
}



for (i=0; i<level.length; i++)
{
if (player.getRect(this).intersects(level[i]))
{
    if (speedX > 0) ////moving right collision and stuffs
        { 
            player.x = level[i].left-player.width/2;
        }
    if (speedX < 0) ////moving left collision and stuffs
        { 
            player.x = level[i].right+player.width/2;
        }
    speedX = 0 //kills the speed
}
}
```

speedX is the speed at which the characters move horizontally, and "platform" is the name of the variable that you're using as the cliff. Also, "player" can be substituted by whatever you are calling your object that's going onto the ledge. That's how I did it in one of my computer classes anyways :) Hope that helps!